# Make an eventReactive execute within a Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I have a selectInput UI object and I would like, once that is used to select an entry from the drop-down choices, to read an RDS file. The `selectInput`'s choices are paths to different `RDS` files. The UI module works fine but the server one doesn't. I get `input$study` and hence `input$dataset1`, and then once I select an entry from input$datasets1 the app should start reading the RDS file but it doesn't.

How do I trigger the eventReactive expression inside the module to run and then make that `RDS` file available to the whole app for other modules to use?

```
load_sce <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$sce_objects <- renderUI({

    validate(need(input$study, message = FALSE))

    withProgress(message = "Getting SCE objects...", {

      objects <- FIND SOME FILES

      ns <- session$ns

      selectInput(inputId = ns("dataset1"),
                  label = "Select a specifc analysis",
                  width = "100%",
                  choices = c("", objects),
                  selected = "")

    }) 
  })


  sce1 <- eventReactive(input$dataset1, {

    validate(need(input$dataset1, message = FALSE))

    withProgress(message = "Reading data...", { readRDS(input$dataset1) })

  }) 



  return( reactive({ sce1 }) )


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would review the documentation for `withProgress` and `Progress`. `withProgress` is for tasks operating inside of a loop. https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/Progress.html

Also, see this example of a module: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html. In order for the dataframe to be returned as a reactive value outside the module, it should be created as a reactive object inside the module and then returned as such. Also, because `input$dataset1` is the only reactive value that `sce1` is dependent upon, `reactive` can be used instead of `eventReactive`. `eventReactive` is better suited for inputs such as buttons that are not actually used within the reactive expression, but simply server as the trigger for the expression to execute.

```
load_sce <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$sce_objects <- renderUI({

    validate(need(input$study, message = FALSE))

      objects <- FIND SOME FILES

      ns <- session$ns

      selectInput(inputId = ns("dataset1"),
                  label = "Select a specifc analysis",
                  width = "100%",
                  choices = c("", objects),
                  selected = "")

    }) 


  sce1 <- reactive({

    validate(need(input$dataset1, message = FALSE))

    progress <- Progress$new(session, min=0, max=1)
    on.exit(progress$close())

    progress$set(message = 'Reading data...')

    dataset1 <- readRDS(input$dataset1)

    progress$set(value = 1)

    return(df)
  }) 

  return(sce1)


}
```

Comment: withProgress works fine in other modules so I don't think that's the problem.Also, what dataframe are you returning in 'return(df)'? I used your solution, kept withProgress and changed return(df) to return(dataset1), works fine. Thanks!

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. I had changed the name from `dataset1` to `df` when running it with a sample dataset locally and failed to change it back when I posted my answer. I was unable to get `withProgress` to work with the correct timing when I was trialling it, so I used `progress` so that I could manually control the progression. If my answer worked for you please accept it - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I used the following in the module function:

```
sce1 <- reactive({

  validate(need(input$dataset1, message = FALSE))

  withProgress(message = "Reading data...", {

    dataset1 <- readRDS(input$dataset1)

  }) # withProgress

  return(dataset1)

}) # reactive


return(sce1)
```

and called the module in the main app using:

```
sce1 <- callModule(load_sce, "load_sce_explore")
```

Now I can pass `sce1` to other modules as a function argument (use `sce1` not `sce1()`) or use it in other pieces of code in the main app (but in this case use `sce1()`).

Thanks